# Set GET params on apps.facebook url per Javascript possible?

Tags: javascript, facebook, api

How do I change the get parameters of the apps.facebook.com URL with JavaScript?

For example, the user selects some photo, so the URL should change to apps.facebook.com/myapp/?photo_id=23234 so the user can simply copy it and give some friend and the friend lands exactly on the same photo and not at the start(home) page.

I don't want to reload the site, but only set the GET - Parameter

Answer (score 0):

```
var appurl = 'http://yourappsite.com/path/to/app';
var pageurl = parent.location.href;
var indexOfQM = pageurl.indexOf('?');
if(indexOfQM > -1)
    window.location.href = appurl+pageurl.substr(pageurl.indexOf('?'));
```

Comment: window.location.href - reload the site?

Comment: Changing the GET parameter will result in a new page load.  If you want to pass data on, use a hashtag.  Change the last line to this: `window.location.href += '#'+appurl+pageurl.substr(pageurl.indexOf('?'));`

Comment: Permission denied to access property 'href'
var pageurl = parent.location.href;